# Why do I get "IndexError: tuple index out of range"?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, reshape

Why do I get the following error message for the bellow code:

```
X_test = []
for i in range(60, 90):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

> X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Why the for loop doesn't make a 30*60 matrix?

Comment: Because ```X_test``` is a 1-d array and so it doesn't have attribute ```X_test.shape[1]```

Comment: Lists are zero-indexed, meaning a one-element list does not have `item[1]`.

Comment: Why it's one-d array? When I am making a matrix in for loop!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your error. Your code runs without any issue in my setting.